# Migrating global.asax to ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Few days ago .NET Core RC1 got released and I gave it a go for the first time after reading a lot about it, I like it but its a bit different. I am trying to migrate a small blog (built in MVC5) to MVC 6 & .NET Core. It wasn't hard but I am really struggling to recreate the exact same global.asax settings I had in MVC 5, ASP.NET 5 no longer has global.asax so I am unable to figure out what the replacement for most of the settings are?

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());

        MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;
        AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;

        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
    }

    protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {
        if (Response.StatusCode != 301 && Response.StatusCode != 302) return;

        var targetUrl = Response.RedirectLocation.Replace("ReturnUrl", "url");
        Response.RedirectLocation = targetUrl;
    }

    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string typeName;

        byte userType = (byte)(Context.Request.IsAuthenticated ? byte.Parse(User.Identity.Name.Split('|')[2]) : 1);

        switch (userType)
        {
            case 1: { typeName = "Client"; break; }
            case 2: { typeName = "Admin"; break; }
            default: { typeName = "Client"; break; }
        }

        var roles = new[] { typeName };

        if (Context.User != null)
        {
            Context.User = new GenericPrincipal(Context.User.Identity, roles);
        }
    }

    private void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

        if (ex is HttpAntiForgeryException)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Server.ClearError();
            Response.Redirect("/error/cookie", true);
        }
    }
```

PLEASE, is there a way to get the above code to work in MVC 6 without leaving any of the settings? This is a deal breaker for me, THANK YOU.

Comment: It would be an interesting experiment to put this code on a github repo and have it side by side with an MVC 6 projects after the conversion. If you end up  pushing the code let me know, I'd like to see what it looks like and what it would take to port it.

Comment: You can do everything that you are doing in global.aspx but though use of custom made middleware. Making middleware in asp.net core is very easy too do. http://andrewlock.net/adding-default-security-headers-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Related post - [How to migrate C# MVC5 Global.asax to ASP.NET Core Startup.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45417665/465053)

Answer (score 7):

Even being an old question I'll put this as I've seen that no one gives a lead how to migrate `global.asax` methods to `Startup.cs`
In the `Configure` section of Startup file, you just need to add

```
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
                {       
                 //this will be call each request.
                 //Add headers      
                    context.Response.Headers.Add();
                 //check response status code
                  if(context.Response.StatusCode == 404) //do something
                 //check user
                 context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated 
                //redirect
                 context.Request.Path = "some url"
                 await next() // will call next logic, in case here would be your controller.
                });
```

That's not a working solution, this is just to show how to work with middleware and applying logic for each request.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This code is a little sloppy, but it does capture all requests.  Solved my problem, thx.

Answer (score 4):

To replace `Application_Start`, put your initialisation code in your Startup class.

`Application_BeginRequest`, `Application_EndRequest`, `Application_AuthenticateRequest` and `Application_Error` can be replaced by a [middleware](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html?highlight=middleware) (`global.asax` is an `HTTP Module` which were replace by `middleware`)

Regarding `Application_AuthenticateRequest`, you should also read the doc about [Request features](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/request-features.html#request-features)

Comment: I understand that, but I cannot find any good tutorial on how to recreate all those middlewares I need. I am just frustrated that the ASP.NET Team would make such a big change and not provide clear documented alternative.

Comment: I'm sure they will. Give them time. Everyone's busy clearing issues on github. Although it's production-ready, it hasn't made it to its first stable release yet.

Comment: @Cindro, There's a sample in the [doc](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html), also check the [Request feature doc](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/request-features.html#middleware-and-request-features) that will help to replace `Application_AuthenticateRequest`

Answer (score 2):

According to [this blogpost](http://wildermuth.com/2015/3/2/A_Look_at_ASP_NET_5_Part_2_-_Startup) from 
Shawn Wildermuth and also he had webinar on Pluralsight about a week ago, where he  told that `MVC 5`  global.asax, packages.config, and web.config are gone in `ASP 5`. So in the `ASP 5` all configuration from former `MVC 5` global.asax goes into new root **Startup.cs** file.

Comment: I understand that, but how can I successfully move all above code to Startup.cs? I only managed to move the routing alone.

Comment: @Cindro Unfortunately it is not easy question since things changed a lot, so I don't know, sorry. For example bundling was almost completely changed: see this post http://www.jeffreyfritz.com/2015/05/where-did-my-asp-net-bundles-go-in-asp-net-5/. Same things for many things which is gone from MVC 5 like global.asax, packages.config, and web.config. So most likely you need to replace most of your code with new one.

Comment: I know, lets hope the solution/alternative way is published soon. Btw, regarding bundling in ASP.NET 5, you can use this package to bundle like in 4.5: https://github.com/Shazwazza/Smidge

Comment: @Cindro Thank you. I will try it.